# Android: text and color on tabs , Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using Tab Layout and I want to do two things:

1. set the color so it won't be gray
2. reduce the text size, the text doesn't fit.

also, the text is in most part on the icon instead of below it (can I do something about it ?).

Any ideas on how can I do this ?

**edit:** I'm creating a new tab in this manner:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator(
    "Artists",
    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)
).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I want to change the size of the word "artists".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your own view.

```
tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator(prepareTabView(this, "title"))
                .setContent(intent);
```

and you can change the text size here **tv.setTextSize(20)"**

```
public static View prepareTabView(Context context, String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabIndicatorTextView);
        tv.setText(text);

        return view;
    }
```

tab_indicator.xml. you can change the text size here also **android:textSize="20dip"**. it is possible to set the background color here. **android:background="@color/back_color_selector_tab"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fakeNativeTabLayout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/back_color_selector_tab">
    <!-- You can even define an Icon here (dont forget to set a custom icon 
        in your code for each Tab): <ImageView android:id="@+id/fakeNativeTabImageView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" /> -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabIndicatorTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tab" android:ellipsize="marquee" />

</LinearLayout>
```

back_color_selector_tab.xml is an xml for automatic changes in background color in different states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background05" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background04" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

a sample of state_orange.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what each part of the code does ? 
I don't see how it does A and B...

Comment: In this sample every thing is in your hands and depend on designing of the tab_indicator.xml file

Comment: I tried using that code and I have some questions: A. on prepareTabView it doesn't recognize R.layout.tab_indicator 
B.can I choose color with hex triplets (like #007FFF) ?
C.  <solid android:color="@color/orange" /> is an error...

Comment: please use the code above completely. A) you should define tab_indicator.xml in layout folder of resources. copy and paste my definition in that file. B) yes you can C) It is a defined color in color.xml file. replace it with #007FFF if it is hard to define a color.xml file

Comment: clean project if eclipse did not recognize your changes.

Comment: I tried again, and the problem I have is that setIndicator recives a CharSequence as parameter but prepareTabView returns view.
thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

For Option A:

```
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));
    }
       tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);
       tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));
```

Comment: can you please explain the two lines after the for ? 
why not tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0), and doesn't the last line changes the backgroung color for only that specific tab ?

Comment: It is used to highlight the current tab background with different color. And then implement OnTabChangeListener so that you can highlight the selected tab in different background then unselected tabs

Comment: thanks, is it also possible to changr the color of that line below the tabs ?