# How to set FragmentTabHost tab text color

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

How to set `FragmentTabHost` tab text color. I tried the following code but, it didn't work.

```
((TextView) mTabHost.getCurrentTabView()
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

It gives NPE saying it couldn't find the `TextView`.

Comment: Refer this this may useful to you..

[change tab color][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783157/android-text-and-color-on-tabs-tab-layout

Comment: Please refer this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853097/874752

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bit tricky. I used the following code and it worked for me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

        final TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);

            // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.(I didn't know, it would return divider too, so I was getting an NPE)
        if (tv == null)
            continue;
        else
            tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let's try this :
for example when you add your tab make your Indicator  : 

    TextView view = ....
    vew.setTextColor(...)
```

then setIndicator with your custom view :

```
 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator(view),
                    FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I want the tab layout to be same as default. If I do this, it will remove the native tab background color.